# Ran batch file invisibly w/ VBScript, w/o cmd window, can't find it in Task Manager

Tags: windows, batch-file, vbscript

I wanted to run a batch file invisibly, without cmd.exe showing. The solution I found online was to make a .vbs file:

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
WshShell.Run chr(34) & "target-bat-file.bat" & Chr(34), 0
Set WshShell = Nothing
```

It works but I can't find the process in Task Manager for the life of me. I'd appreciate it if you could point me to it.

Knowing barely anything about cybersec, it does make me wonder how secure Windows really is but that's outside the scope of the post :)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cmd.exe is the batch interpreter, it has to be running to execute a batch file. All your VBScript is doing is hiding the console window.

You will see cmd.exe in Task manager and if you look at the command line (details tab) it will look something like `c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /c "c:\path\mybatch.bat"`.